# SQL Mass Character Removal

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, replace

Alright, so we have a database right now that's got user login and save state info. The save state is pretty much just a JSON blob, but the client we issued has a bug in it where a '\' character gets generated, and then every subsequent time a user logs in a new '\' is added for each '\'. This is causing a pretty serious amount of wonkiness if the user logs out and back in enough times - ultimately resulting in the user not being able to log in anymore.

We fixed the client but all those save states are unusable until we fix them.

End goal here is to hit the database with an SQL query to try and drop all the '\' when there is more than one of them in a row. Recommendations? Maybe some kind of REPLACE call?

Comment: What is the type of database being used, e.g. SQL Server?

Comment: its postgres, i can definitely run SQL against it

Comment: From a glance at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html), something along the lines of `regexp_replace(column, '\\{2,}', '')` should do as a replacement function. (The first backslash is to escape the second one.)

Comment: I hit it with

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("tableName", '\\{2,}', '') FROM table

but it didnt seem to work. query executes succesfully, I wonder if its just removing a subset of the total amount of '\' chars? I'll keep digging into it though, the regexp_replace definitely seems like a good starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
UPDATE yourTable SET JsonBlob = regexp_replace(JsonBlob, '\\{2,}', '');
```

where `'\\{2,}'` means two-or-more backslashes. The first backslash is to escape the second backslash. It must be a POSIX regular expression.

PostgreSQL 9.5.3 documentation: [9.4. String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html).

Comment: can i just use the column name as the first argument in the regexp_replace call? or do i need to go through and select the json blob explicitly.

Comment: @TSI25 Thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into CTEs.  They allow you to recursively call back into data until a specific criteria is hit.  In this case, you would recursively call REPLACE(myString, '\', '') until the count of \'s is 1.

This will handle the case where there could be anywhere from 1 slash to 1000+ slashes.

Comment: OP updated to specify Postgres.  I know absolutely 0 about Postgres and whether my posted solution is still viable or not.

Comment: Also, I like @Andrew Morton's answer in the comments more than my posted solution.  I wasn't aware of the regexp_replace() function; that's very cool.

Comment: Some databases have regexes; Microsoft's SQL Server is a notable exception - I guess they see CLR functions as a usable alternative.